# Middlebrook's Method VS Tian's Method VS Middlebrook's General Feedback Theorem

Tags: feedback, loop-gain

For https://sites.google.com/site/frankwiedmann/loopgain , how is [Tian's Method](https://github.com/Ribster/LTSpice/blob/master/LTS0001%20-%20Examples%20REV%20A/Educational/LoopGain2.asc) different compared to [Middlebrook's Method](https://github.com/Ribster/LTSpice/blob/master/LTS0001%20-%20Examples%20REV%20A/Educational/LoopGain.asc) and [Middlebrook's General Feedback Theorem](https://sites.google.com/site/frankwiedmann/loopgain/GFT_LTspice_XVII.zip?attredirects=0) ?

**Tian's Method**
[image: Tian's Method]

**Middlebrook's Method**
[image: Middlebrook's Method]

**Middlebrook GFT Method**
[image: Middlebrook GFT Method]

Comment: Those pictures are too small and contain math elements that are better suited (and infinitely more readable) using mathjax instead.

Comment: 1) measures v(f) i(f) simultaneously, 2) separately 3) ?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 How does Tian's method accounts for reverse feedback ? What does it mean by **the inserted probe elements result in smaller, sparser circuit matrix** ?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 For Middlebrook method, why use "V2 = AC 1" on the feedback path ?

Comment: I think the matrix refers to scattering parameters of input or output impedance with forward and reverse transfer functions.  http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/723/handouts/section_4_3_The_Scattering_Matrix_package.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yeah, see page 3 of paper : [Comparative Analysis of Simulation-Based Methods for Deriving the Phase- and Gain-Margins of Feedback Circuits With Op-Amps](https://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6977998)

but why Tian's method resulted in smaller matrix ?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Besides, how to derive equations 7 and 8 of [Dissection Theorem of Middlebrook's GFT method](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4537/1/MIDieeemm06.pdf#page=3) ?

Comment: Answering those, is not my strength, but perhaps this may help. https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/3105743/file/3105746.pdf where (this is news to me ) Tian's gain is \$T_t=T_{fwd}+T_{rev}\$